# Pegar imagem da galeria no android

Tags: android

Gostaria que abrisse na Galeria de Imagens e não em Imagem

```
contactImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); //coloquei assim, esta certo ?
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);
       }
});
```

Quando eu abro pelo emulado do *bluestack*, ao invés de no `Intent` abrir direto na galeria, ele abre em Image e dai eu preciso selecionar a galeria, mas só que eu queria que abrisse direto em Galeria, tem como ?

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta passar a `URI` do [Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html).

```
Intent galeriaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(galeriaIntent);
```

Comment: eu coloquei o seu código em troca do meu, ele esta abrindo a galeria agora, só que ele não esta fazendo as outras funções de pegar a imagem que eu selecionei, vou editar o post